# MultiDimensional UILabel Array in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to create a UIView like in the picture. I want to have 9 squares  each contain 1 Main label and 6 other label as in picture. What is the best way to achieve.

[image]

Comment: This looks like a grid. It's better to use `UICollectionView` for things like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use collectionView with vertical scrolling and make the width for each cell

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    // 10 is spacing between cells

    let w =  (collectionView.frame.width - 2 * 10 ) / 3

    return CGSize(width: w, height:100)
}3
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a UIView subclass add labels inside that class, Consider  UIView subclass' object as your primary object do all the other label handling inside that, this approach will be much easier to handle as it provides cleaner code to maintain.